# MySql: query to add and categorize distinct data based on date

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to extract the total number of 'Posts' each unique users posts per month and categorize it between 2-3 posts and 4+ posts. Please see example below. Can't get it to work right, please help.

Example DB:

```
id         Date                    ID             Posts     otherData
-----      ------                  -------        ------    -----------
1          2015-01-24 14:13:50     user1           1        2
2          2015-01-24 14:13:50     user1           3        1
3          2015-01-24 14:13:50     user2           2        4
4          2015-01-24 14:13:50     user3           7        3
5          2015-01-24 14:13:50     user4           0        2
6          2015-02-24 04:13:50     user1           1        3
7          2015-02-24 04:13:50     user1           1        1
8          2015-02-24 04:13:50     user3           1        2
```

Expected results:

```
Month     totalUsersThatHavePosted    1 post     2-3Posts          4+Posts
-----     -------------------------   ------     ---------         ------- 
12015     3                           0          1                 2
22015     2                           1          1                 0
```

I'm trying queries like this (but don't think I'm close):

```
SELECT CONCAT( MONTH(  `Date` ) , YEAR(  `Date` ) ) AS Month, COUNT(DISTINCT `ID`) 
FROM  `myDB` 
WHERE  `Posts` >0
GROUP BY CONCAT( MONTH(  `Date` ) , YEAR(  `Date` ) )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this will give you what you want:

```
SELECT 
Month,COUNT(DISTINCT(user_total)) AS totalUsersThatHavePosted,
SUM((user_total) = 1) as 1_post,
SUM((user_total) in (2, 3)) as 2_3_posts, 
SUM((user_total) > (3)) as 4_plus_posts 
FROM 
(
    SELECT CONCAT(MONTH(Date),
    YEAR(Date)) AS Month,
    ID,
    SUM(Posts) AS user_total 
    FROM myDB 
    WHERE Posts > 0
    GROUP BY Date,ID
) 
AS desired_subset 

GROUP BY Month;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a double aggregation query.  First, aggregate by the user and month, to get the count.  Then aggregate by the month for the final counts:

```
select yr, mon, count(*) as TotalUsersPosted,
       sum(cnt in (2, 3)) as posts_2_3,
       sum(cnt >= 4) as posts_4pl 
from (select id, year(date) as yr, month(date) as mon, count(*) as cnt
      from mydb
      group by id, year(date), month(date)
     ) t
group by yr, mon
```

Comment: I apologize, I made an edit, see line 5 of the sample database.  How do I not include users who have not posted.

Comment: You would add the `where` clause to the subquery.